# How to fix "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

Please help check the code to see where there is error as I am not a coder but just using the application from another developer

```
            <div class="bs-example widget-shadow table-responsive" data-example-id="hoverable-table"> 
                <table class="table table-hover"> 
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th>ID</th> 
                            <th>Client name</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Payment mode</th>
                            <th>Receiver's email</th>
                            <th>Status</th> 
                            <th>Date created</th>
                            <th>Option</th>
                        </tr> 
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody> 
                        @foreach($withdrawals as $deposit)
                        <tr> 
                            <th scope="row">{{$deposit->id}}</th>
                            <td>{{$deposit->duser->name}}</td>
                             <td>{{$deposit->amount}}</td> 
                             <td>{{$deposit->payment_mode}}</td> 
                             <td>{{$deposit->duser->email}}</td> 
                             <td>{{$deposit->status}}</td> 
                             <td>{{$deposit->created_at}}</td> 
                             <td> <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('dashboard/pwithdrawal') }}/{{$deposit->id}}">Process</a></td> 
                        </tr> 
                        @endforeach
```

Comment: if you do not write what and where your problem is we can not solve it

Comment: you have need to check  '$withdrawals' data in controller. Maybe It's not coming in object format.

Comment: you have to check whether the $withdrawals is empty or not before iteration.

Comment: Show us the controller function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `{{$deposit->duser->name}}` and `{$deposit->duser->email}}`. Every withdrawal must have a valid user ID. This user ID will be matched against user table and the name and email of that user will be showed in blade.

What is happening is this, one or more $deposit has invalid user ID. So, the blade is trying to search in the table to get the name and email. But it is not finding it. So essentially it is trying to get the name value of a null object and crashing the app.

You can try to check if the duser have a null value by using following code,

```
@foreach($withdrawals as $deposit)

    @if(!is_null($deposit->duser))

     <tr> 
      <th scope="row">{{$deposit->id}}</th>
      <td>{{$deposit->duser->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$deposit->amount}}</td> 
      <td>{{$deposit->payment_mode}}</td> 
      <td>{{$deposit->duser->email}}</td> 
      <td>{{$deposit->status}}</td> 
      <td>{{$deposit->created_at}}</td> 
      <td> <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('dashboard/pwithdrawal') }}/{{$deposit->id}}">Process</a></td> 
                        </tr> 

    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: so what should I do'

Comment: For now, try finding the withdrawals with invalid user manually and delete them from DB. Make sure when inserting no value should be entered without a valid user.